# STM32F407VG Disc board won't connect anymore

Tags: arm, reset, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

**Context**

I have accidentally uploaded some ARM Cortex M0-cmis files (core-cmFunc.h and core_cmInstr.h) to the STM32F407VG discovery board. After I noticed my mistake, I tried to undo it by changing my code and upload it again... but it said it couldn't make connection.

**What I already tried**

I've tried to get passed the USART interface of the discovery board by uploading the code directly on the ARM Coretex M4 chip via the bootloader. I connected BOOT0 to VDD and PB2(=BOOT1) to GND so the chip starts up in the Pattern1-mode. Then I connected PA9(=Tx) and PA10(=Rx) to an USB to TTL cable (by the use of a RS-232 chip in the cable) and reset the device. I started the "Flash Loader Demonstrator" from ST to make connection with the board (I've done this before and it worked). But that didn't made connection either.

**Extra information**

1. The Windows filemanager "sees" the ARM Cortex M4 file when it gets connected to the PC;
2. Led LD7 emits green light when the board is powered;
3. Led LD1 emits red light;

Does someone knows how I can factory-reset the flashmemmory of the STM32F4 so it acts at it should again?

Comment: Can you connect to the board using STM32 ST-Link Utility software from ST?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I've come to the conclusion that I accidentally activated the OTG_VBUS with my code. I couldn't upload another code because that bus was active on PA9(TX of USART2). It seems that the VBUS was held active, even in bootloader mode.

[PA9 connected to VBUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ6FO.png)

The solution to this problem was the use of another bootloader interface, I used USART3 on PB10/11, but you could also use PC10/11. After I uploaded a dummy code in that manner, I 
was able to upload codes with the Coocox-IDE again.

[Other Bootloader interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1giRC.png)